# How to get URLinformation after question mark?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code:

```
<a href="subsc.php?English" class="price_button pb_red">Subscribe today</a>
```

when the user press on the `a` tag it takes him to the page `subsc.php?English`.
My question is how can i get the information after the `?` (which is "English" in this example)?

Comment: `window.location.search`

Comment: Prefixing your question title with “javascript” and typing it into Google, would have lead you there straight away. Please make an actual research effort, before you ask about stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Regex Positive Lookbehind `/(?<=\?).$*/`.

```js
var url = '/subsc.php?English';
var r = url.match(/(?<=\?).*$/)[0];
console.log(r);
```